# url rewriting for 404 page

Tags: php, .htaccess

suppose i have a file missing at
http://www.mydomain.com/user/10202.html i.e user.php
then the server gives me 404 page default error....
than i add the following to my .htaccess file

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
```

but it redirects me to http://www.mydomain.com/404.html while i want to stay on
http://mydomain.com/user/10202.html and show the 404.html how can i do that...

Comment: Is that your actual configuration? And are there any other configurations that might conflict with this one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use RewriteCond ant RewriteRule from mod_rewrite.

```
# If file doesn't exist, i display 404.html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /404.html [L]
```

Answer (score 2):

I use this two lines in my .htaccess and the link remains on the non existing (it does not redirect to error_404.html)

```
ErrorDocument 404 /error_404.html
RewriteRule ^error_([0-9]+).(html|php)$ error.php?error=error$1 [QSA,NC]
```

This works for actual files that doesn't exist but also for rewrites that are not matched correctly. In the error.php I log the error to a debugging database.